# supervisord disable log files or use logfile=/dev/stdout

Tags: docker, supervisord

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/stdout
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor
```

When I do this supervisor will crash because it cannot seek in /dev/stdout

How can I disable supervisord creating any log files in my docker container?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the main supervisor, `nodaemon` will cause logs to go to `stdout`

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Then send the logs for each managed process to the stdout file descriptor `/dev/fd/1`

```
[program:x]
command=echo test
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
redirect_stderr=true
```

Or if you prefer to keep stderr on a different stream:

```
[program:x]
command=echo test
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Comment: This works but stdout logs for [supervisord] specifically will now be displayed twice in the console

Comment: Ah of course, because `nodaemon` already logs there. Send it to `/dev/null` instead

Comment: it happens the same to me (twice log in the console). What I have to send to `/dev/null`? @Matt thanks

Comment: @loretoparisi `logfile=/dev/null` for `supervisord` (the answer was updated to include that after the previous comments)

Comment: @Matt thanks in my casse it does no work see my config here https://stackoverflow.com/q/56875104/758836

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove the `logfile` in your supervisord.conf and every logs will show as container logs when you enter `docker logs <container_id> --tail=100 -f`

Comment: If I remove `logfile=...` the default is applied and creates a logfile in the working directorie

Answer (score -1):

I am with same problem so I checked supervisor documentation and the best way finded was:

```
[program:myservice]
command=/usr/local/bin/myservice.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
```

In my case I keeped logfile_backup with value 3 and maxbytes 10000000 because I need this, I hope be help someone.